# Child Component Making Use of Parents' Prop in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-props, react-component

I am creating a form Component that will have a `Form` component and an `Input` component.  Something like this:

```
<Form>
  <Input name="name" />
  <Input name="email" />
</Form>
```

In my setup, labels are automatically get generated from the `name` prop.  What I would like to do, though, is provide an option to not show labels.  Now, I could do it on each `<Input>` component like this:

```
<Form>
  <Input noLabel name="name" />
  <Input noLabel name="email" />
</Form>
```

But what I would really like to do is add it to the `<Form>` component and have it automatically applied to each `<Input>` component.  Something like this:

```
<Form noLabel>
  <Input name="name" />
  <Input name="email" />
</Form>
```

The way I envision it, when defining my `<Input>` component I could do a check if the noLabel prop is set on the `<Form>` component.  Something like this:

```
export const Input = props => {
  ...
  {!props.noLabel && <label>...}
  <input.../>
  ...
}
```

But I can't figure out how to get access to the `noLabel` prop from the `<Form>` component so that I can check to see whether or not it is set.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: What version of react are you using? is it 16.4 and higher?

Comment: I'm using 16.8.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would choose the context approach, to overcome the problems I mentioned in my comment to Mohamed's solution, this would enable indirect nesting as well:

```
const FormContext = React.createContext();

const Form = ...;

Form.Context = FormContext; // or simply Form.Context = React.createContext();

export default ({noLabel, ...props}) => <FormContext.Provider value={{noLabel}}/>;
```

and then your input component will consume it either like this:

```
const Input = props => {
  const {noLabel} = useContext(Form.Context);

  return (... < your no label logic here > ...);
}
```

or like this:

```
const Input = ....;

export default props => () => {
  const {noLabel} = useContext(Form.Context);

  return <Input noLabel={noLabel}/>
}
```

Comment: Thanks Meir -- I like the idea of using context.  Very elegant.

Answer (score 2):

In your `Form` component, you can use `React.Children` and `React.cloneElement` to pass the `noLabel` prop to the input components,  something like this :

```
const children = React.Children.map(this.props.children, child =>
  React.cloneElement(child, { noLabel: this.props.noLabel  })
);

return (<form>{children}</form>);
```

Comment: Looks like we've synchronized our thoughts here ahahahh

Comment: Are there any downsides to this method?  I.e., in terms of performance or anything else?  I.e., is the gain that I get in only using one prop on the Form component lost in terms of performance or some other cost associated with doing this?

Comment: @Moshe I think there are 2 issues with this approach:
1. If the element is not `<Input...>` you duplicate it without a need, and you add a field that might raise error with react (react can complain about props with unrecognized names to primitives such as div, span etc.)
2. The Input elements have to be nested directly in the form, any intermediate layout element (row, column etc.) will break the passing of the property

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it is manipulating `form`'s `children`. Mapping over each one and inject  `noLabel` `prop`. You still will need to check inside `Input` for a `noLabel` `prop` but it's definitely less work

```
const Form = ({children, noLabel}) =>{
    return React.children.forEach(_, child =>{
        return React.cloneElement(child, { noLabel })
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks -- please note my comment on Mohamed's answer -- which, as you noted, is the same as yours :).

Comment: It's just like mapping an array. As long as your form doesn't have an absurd quantity of `inputs` this won't be a performance issue